# Predicate with NSSet

Tags: swift, predicate

I'm trying to filter results from core data based on the users search text which is working fine. I'm struggling with making it so that there are several key terms that bring back specific results.

I have a `Colour` entity, which has a `to-many` relationship with another entity, `ProjectColour`. The `ProjectColour` entity has two fields I want to search by `fullLeft` and `partialLeft`.

What I'd like to do is when I search for the term "full" to bring back any `Colour` that has the `ProjectColour` field `fullLeft > 0`.

The same for `partialLeft` and again or all.

So far, I have this but am unsure how to the predicate for checking the objects in the `NSSet`

```
    if ( searchedText.count > 0 ) {
        if searchedText == "full" {

        } else if searchedText == "partial" {

        } else if searchedText == "all" {

        } else {
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[cd] %@", searchedText)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for "ANY"? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076452/difference-between-all-any-and-some-operators-in-nspredicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved it with the following

```
    if ( searchedText.count > 0 ) {
        if searchedText.lowercased() == "full" {
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY projectColours.fullLeft > 0")
        } else if searchedText.lowercased() == "partial" {
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY projectColours.partialLeft > 0")
        } else if searchedText.lowercased() == "all" {
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY projectColours.fullLeft > 0 OR ANY projectColours.partialLeft > 0")
        } else {
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[cd] %@", searchedText)
        }
    }
```